# Why does the cold air coming down from an ice cream oscillate?

Tags: everyday-life, drag, air, vortex

It occurred to me that when I held a choc-ice the other day (a wooden paddle with a chocolate ice-cream above it with two large smooth sides) that I could occasionally feel cold air falling down onto my hands below it and remarked on this great example of convection.

However, upon thinking about it more, I realised the coldness **came in waves**, suggesting that somehow cold air coming down a flat surface had a tendency to form a stable oscillatory process. My question is **why and can we create any relatively simple quantitative predictions/explanations of it?**

As I understand it, the cold falling down will have a viscous-flow component that drags close to the wall of the choc-ice and it could be that this creates a series of vortices as the air passes the edge (a roughly 90$^\circ$ angle) of the choc-ice to the paddle but this is all terribly qualitative and I hoped that someone who actually knows something about airflow could explain this.

Comment: Are you sure it is a stable oscillating flow and not just constant  fluctuations in the fluid flow? Just like when you see random flickering in a flaming fire burning?

Comment: It seemed relatively stable at the time, though I admit this is a qualitative claim. I shall later add to this post any actually timed experiments I undertake.

Comment: A simple explanation is the convection model https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1433064

Comment: This [youtube at 2:15](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmS6h_fkPgk). Unfortunately she did not hold the freeze pop still. You can do [Synthetic Schlieren Imaging](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/synthetic-schlieren-imaging.963142/) yourself with just a computer monitor or TV and a camera and some free software.